# How to style selected radio button

Tags: html, css

My HTML is like this

```
    <div class="col-md-12 money-radio-container">
  <input type="radio" name="optradio" class="money-radio" value="10">10 <span>$</span>
  <input type="radio" name="optradio" class="money-radio" value="20">20 <span>$</span>
  <input type="radio" name="optradio" class="money-radio" value="50">50 <span>$</span>
</div>
```

Now I want to give red color to which ever radio button is selected. How can I achieve this through CSS?

Note: As you may have noticed When i click on each radio button no html change happens. So i don't know how to identify selected one.
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rrmzvkag/3/

Comment: You should probably look into `:checked`

Comment: @AndyHolmes I already tried it here. but not working https://jsfiddle.net/rrmzvkag/3/

Comment: That's because it's not `type="checked"`. It's `input[type="radio"]:checked`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS rule would be

```
input[type="radio"]:checked
```

Unsure what exactly what you want to do but if you were planning on doing some styling on the  element which goes after each radio element in your question you'd use the following rule

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + span
```

Comment: I have tried it here. But not working
https://jsfiddle.net/rrmzvkag/2/

Comment: Can you send me an updated Fiddle with correct resolution?

Comment: You did not even write the CSS I provided in the answer. Jesus.

Comment: Sorry, Wrong fiddle. this is the correct one https://jsfiddle.net/rrmzvkag/3/

Comment: No it's not - you're saying type="checkbox" in your fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/rrmzvkag/4/

Comment: That latest link makes the span's colour red when the radio button is checked, the rest is yours.